# What is the PLSR implementation in sklearn?

Tags: svd, latent-variable, partial-least-squares

Having a look to the [source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/15a949460/sklearn/cross_decomposition/_pls.py#L502) from `sklear` implementation of `PLSRegression` I see two differences between what they cite as their reference and what they actually implement:

- The `y_weights` in the algorithm are not normalized, but in the reference paper they are.
- The deflation of $Y$ matrix is performed on a different manner than the one stated in their reference paper.

I have seen these differences in the implemenntation of PLS also in R, and I want to understand where they are coming from. Going into more details about the differences:

In the sklearn source code it is stated that the main reference for their implementation is:

> Main ref: Wegelin, a survey of Partial Least Squares (PLS) methods, with emphasis on the two-block case
> https://www.stat.washington.edu/research/reports/2000/tr371.pdf

In pages 9 and 10 of the pdf file, what they call "PLS-C2A" is described in detail.

### Differences in `y_weights`

Specifically, at the begining of page 10 it is specified that `y_weights` ($v_r$ in the document) is computed as the right singular vector of matrix $(X^{r})^{t}Y^{r}$.

This is done in the sklearn algorithm by using the power method (function `_get_first_singular_vectors_power_method`)

where they compute, for the `x_weihts`:

```
x_weights = np.dot(X.T, y_score) / np.dot(y_score, y_score)
x_weights /= np.sqrt(np.dot(x_weights, x_weights)) + eps
```

This would be equivalent to

$$u_r = \dfrac{(X^r)^t\omega}{\omega^t\omega}$$
$$u_r = \frac{u_r}{\|u_r\|}$$

And for the `y_weights`
y_weights = np.dot(Y.T, x_score) / np.dot(x_score.T, x_score)

Equivalent to
$$v_r = \dfrac{(Y^r)^t\xi}{\xi^t\xi}$$

But they do not normalize $v_r$ after that. **Why not?**

### Differences in Y deflation

In section 8 (page 24) of the paper it is specified how the deflation process is performed in PLS2 algorithm:

$$
\beta_{r} \leftarrow\left(\xi_{r}^{T} \xi_{r}\right)^{-1} \xi_{r}^{T} \omega_{r}
$$
and $\mathrm{Y}^{(r)}$ is updated as follows:
$$
\mathrm{Y}^{(r+1)} \leftarrow Y^{(r)}-\beta_{r} \xi_{r} \omega_{r}^{T}
$$

But in sklearnn, the deflationn process is performed as

```
y_loadings = np.dot(x_scores, Yk) / np.dot(x_scores, x_scores)
Yk -= np.outer(x_scores, y_loadings)
```

which would be equivalent to
$$
\delta_{r}^{T}=\xi{r}^{T} Y^{(r)}\left(\xi{r}^{T} \xi{r}\right)^{-1} 
$$

$$
\mathbf{Y}^{(r+1)} \leftarrow \mathbf{Y}^{(r)}-\omega_{r} \delta_{r}^{T}
$$

So, **¿why this difference?**